# Implement keys local language erreur

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
class MyLocale implements Translations {
  @override
  Map<String,Map<String,String>> get Keys => {
"ar": {},
 "en":{}, };
  };

  @override
  // TODO: implement keys
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

[this the erreur photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya3Gh.jpg)

im trying to fix this erreur to run my application pliz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like this if you use GetX

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class MyTranslation extends Translations {
@override
Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
    "ar": {,
      "1": "اختر اللغه",

    },
    "en": {
      "1": "Choose Language",
     }

  };
}
```